# how to use if else in sql server with where clause

Tags: sql

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findlist @comedianname1 nvarchar(30),@comedianname2 nvarchar(30)
AS
SELECT comedian 
FROM Comedian
if @comedianname2!=null
begin
WHERE comedian! = @comedianname1 and comedian! = @comedianname2
end
else
begin
WHERE comedian! = @comedianname1
end
GO
```

I am getting this  error :  Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Procedure findlist, Line 7
Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'WHERE'.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not use `IF` in select. You could do this instead in your case:

```
SELECT comedian 
FROM Comedian
WHERE
    comedian! = @comedianname1 AND
    comedian! = ISNULL(@comedianname2, comedian!)
```

What does it do? If compares `comedian!` to `@comedianname1` and if `@comedianname2` is not null, it compares `comedian!` to `@comedianname2`. Otherwise it compares `comedian!` to `comedian!`, which is always `true`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use the below query

```
SELECT comedian 
FROM Comedian
WHERE comedian! = @comedianname1 and (comedian! = @comedianname2 OR @comedianname2 IS NULL)
```

Comment: I'd swap the `IS NOT NULL` and `comedian! = @comedianname2`. Just to make sure that the field comparison is not done unless `@comedianname2` really is not null.

Comment: @Thorsten Dittmar Good suggestion.. +1

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
CREATE PROCEDURE findlist @comedianname1 nvarchar(30),@comedianname2 nvarchar(30)
AS
  SELECT comedian 
  FROM Comedian
  WHERE (comedian! = @comedianname1 and comedian! = @comedianname2) OR (comedian! = @comedianname1)
GO
```